# Getting list of all documents from share point

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to implement functionality where I can get list of documents from share-point.I have tried this demo code from Azure directory implementation and login to account and also got details about sites and user data from graph API.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-kotlin

I am able to get site data from graph API :

[image]

But when I am trying to get list then getting error or no value

[image]

I have also passed this authorization token to REST API but that too doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this answer helps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57297510/7821823

Comment: Hi @MarioVarchmin I have tried this as well. no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with scope `Sites.ReadWrite.All` instead of `User.read`, as I tested it using Graph Explorer and I got access denied as the scope permission was not consented. After I consent the permission, it worked .

**Example 1:**

**Before Consent:**

[image]

**After Constent:**

I have created a test list on the Communication Site.

[image]

After that when I query for lists , I successfully get the above one I created.

[image]

**Example 2 :**

I also tested it using a Application registered to Azure AD. It didn't return me any error or any value as well when I queried for lists using that app's credential's from Powershell.

[image]

After I add `Sites.ReadWrite.All` to the App's API permission's .

[image]

I can successfully get the Values of the lists.

[image]

**To summarize it , it could be resolved in 2 ways :**

> 1. Changing the Scope shown on the screenshot given by you to `Sites.ReadWrite.All` instead of `User.Read`.
> 2. Adding API permissions to the APP registration in the Azure AD for Microsoft Graph as shown in the example 2 second image.