# Invalid Audience: Unable to list federated Sharepoint Online via Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-logic-apps

### Context

We have a Logic App in our tenant that, triggered by the presence of certain files in our blob storage, must copy them to our customer's Sharepoint Online. It is basically a drop-folder for reciprocal data exchange (yes, we will be picking files from Sharepoint the next episode).

We have created a simple task in Azure Logic App to list Sharepoint files. It is configured in order for site url and folder to scan to be mapped by parameters at runtime.

[image: GUI model]

```json
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline_1']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['SiteAddress']))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['LibraryName']))}/getfileitems",
        "queries": {
            "folderPath": "@triggerBody()?['FolderPath']",
            "viewScopeOption": "Default"
        }
    }
}
```

When we test this on our Sharepoint online (e.g. `SiteUrl` being `https://contoso.sharepoint.com` it works with our API connection).

When we need to reach the customer's Sharepoint, we will be pointing to something like `https://acme.sharepoint.com` and the user in the connection API (`user@contoso.com`) is already authorized by the IT department of the foreign company **as a guest user** in AD Online to access Sharepoint Online.

### Problem

When we run the Logic App onto the customer's Sharepoint, it fails because of an authentication error

Input parameters:

```json
{
    "headers": {
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
        "Expect": "100-continue",
        "Host": "prod-238.westeurope.logic.azure.com",
        "Content-Length": "241",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "BlobPath": "/readme.txt", #blob storage pattern
        "SiteAddress": "https://acme.com/sites/example",
        "SiteRootFolder": "foo", #blob storage folder
        "LibraryName": "bar", #sharepoint library
        "FolderPath": "spam" #sharepoint folder
    }
}
```

Against these parameters (redacted), the outcome of the "Get Files (properties only)" step was: **Unauthorized**

Input

```json
{
    "method": "get",
    "queries": {
        "folderPath": "spam",
        "viewScopeOption": "Default"
    },
    "path": "/datasets/https%253A%252F%252Facme.sharepoint.com%252Fsites%252Fexample/tables/bar/getfileitems",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/0000000000000000000000/resourceGroups/example/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sharepointonline"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-diagnostics": "3000003;reason=\"Invalid audience Uri 'https://acme.sharepoint.com/'.\";category=\"invalid_client\"",
        "SPRequestGuid": "985ae0eb-e96a-4484-8f02-056c7718fa6f",
        "request-id": "985ae0eb-e96a-4484-8f02-056c7718fa6f",
        "MS-CV": "6+BamGrphESPAgVsdxj6bw.0",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
        "X-FRAME-OPTIONS": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com *.dynamics.com;",
        "SPRequestDuration": "12",
        "SPIisLatency": "1",
        "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices": "16.0.0.21924",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-MS-InvokeApp": "1; RequireReadOnly",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
        "Cache-Control": "private",
        "Date": "Fri, 10 Dec 2021 11:02:29 GMT",
        "P3P": "CP=\"ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI\"",
        "WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer realm=\"d9dbc877-29e4-4473-9855-d3db78ae431b\",client_id=\"00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000\",trusted_issuers=\"00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*,D3776938-3DBA-481F-A652-4BEDFCAB7CD8@*,https://sts.windows.net/*/,00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@90140122-8516-11e1-8eff-49304924019b\",authorization_uri=\"https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize\"",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Length": "130",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "error_description": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."
    }
}
```

### Investigation

I have tried to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297510/error-descriptionexception-of-type-microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-audienceu) but it looks like lower-level programming. We are using Azure Logic Apps that authenticate themselves independently. We are not coding in lanuages such as C# to manage the app authentication

I have tried to read [this post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Unable-to-get-Item-getting-AudienceUriValidationFailedException/td-p/367502) but both the front end is slightly changed, and we have triple-checked that the connection is correct and `user@contoso.com` can access ACME sharepoint

Looks like, judging from the error, that Azure Logic App tries to obtain a JWT token from Microsoft Online whose audience (`aud`) is `https://acme.sharepoint.com` which **should be correct**, but Sharepoint is refusing it claiming to be bad audience.

In OAuth/JWT, it is normal for a resource service to reject tokens when audience does not match self.

## Question

Why does Sharepoint Online refuse the authentication?

We have no visibility over the user configuration on the foreign side, **but** I would be glad to **ask the correct questions** to the other IT.